# Java ResultSet out of memory, can't update with PreparedStatement

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, resultset

I've been loading a growing and growing ResultSet into memory and until now it really hasn't been an issue. It is now too large to reasonably work with. I've looked into creating scrollable result sets, however I'm having some trouble implementing it. Here's what I've tried:

```
    Statement stmt = con.createStatement(java.sql.ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, java.sql.ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
    stmt.setFetchSize(Integer.MIN_VALUE);
    try {

        if (stmt.execute("SELECT text, value FROM " + db)) {
            rs = stmt.getResultSet();
        } else {
            System.err.println("select failed");
        }
```

Is there some other parameter for the Statement that I'm missing? Or is there another option that I have to set somewhere else?

**EDIT:**

Turns out the issue wasn't the stream itself, but how I was updating the RS. Can I not update the RS if it's streaming? Console is popping off the following:

```
SQLException: Operation not supported for streaming result sets
SQLState: S1009
VendorError: 0
```

Here's the code I'm using to update the DB after they've been processed:

```
rs.getDouble("value");
if (rs.wasNull()) {
StringValue analysis = new StringValue(dict);
int id = rs.getRow();
String entry = rs.getString("text");
double val = analysis.analyzeString(entry);
pst.setDouble(1, val);
st.setInt(2, id);
System.out.println(id+": " + val + " : " + rs.getString(5));
pst.executeUpdate();
```

The prepared statement is structured like so:

```
pst = conn.prepareStatement("UPDATE "+ db +" SET value=? WHERE id=?");
```

Fairly straightforward, StringValue method analyzeString is essentially sentiment analysis of the input string.

Comment: your problem most likely has nothing to do with the ResultSet and everything to do with how you are handling the data you read _from_ the ResultSet.

Comment: I concur with @jtahlborn. Maybe you can post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) version of your code for us to look at.

Comment: @Sujay @jthalbom I will. I think I ironed out the issue with getting the stream, now I'm getting a `SQLException: Operation not supported for streaming result sets`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Limit your rows:

```
"select text, value from " + db  + " limit 100"
```

or

```
"select  text,value from " + db  + " where text like 'A%'"
```

Answer (score 0):

I advise you to add some parameters for JVM in order to enlarge JVM memory, such as -Xmx, -Xms, you can refer to [JVM Memory Structure](http://www.yourkit.com/docs/kb/sizes.jsp) to get more details.

Comment: if your data is continually growing, increasing heap size without any other code changes is at best a stop-gap measure.

Comment: I've been giving it about 4 gigs, need to fix it in code now.

Comment: Based on the given information, I've not idea about table structure and can't find out any problems about the codes, so I think that it's likely caused by loading too many objects into memory.

Answer (score 0):

> Statement stmt = con.createStatement(java.sql.ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, java.sql.ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);

You should use
    Statement stmt = con.createStatement(java.sql.ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,java.sql.ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);

Comment: Thought this would work, however I still run out of heap space.